# Using `mpirun` within a Jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, mpi, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a simple C/MPI code :

```
/* File: demo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int my_rank,nprocs;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    printf("Processor [%d] : Hello, World! (world=%d processor(s))\n",my_rank,nprocs);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

When I run this inside of an interactive Python shell, I get the expected output :

```
In [1]: !mpirun -n 4 demo
Processor [1] : Hello, World! (world=4 processor(s))
Processor [3] : Hello, World! (world=4 processor(s))
Processor [2] : Hello, World! (world=4 processor(s))
Processor [0] : Hello, World! (world=4 processor(s))

In [2]:
```

However, when I run the same command inside of a Jupyter notebook, I get four serial jobs:

[image]

Is there a better way to call the `mpirun` script from within a notebook?  I've tried `%%bash` magic and subprocess, but these produces the same results.

I am interested in running MPI codes from notebooks as an easy way to collect run time data to store and display.  I am not so interested in writing parallel Python programs.

I am running Python 3.6.3 (Anaconda), on OSX 10.13.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (partial) answer is the following.  For reasons I do not completely understand, Jupyter notebook and the interactive shell where using different search paths to find `mpirun`.

In IPython :

```
In [1]: !type mpirun
mpirun is /opt/local/bin/mpirun
```

But in the notebook, I have :

[image]

Using this version of `mpirun` from the bash prompt, I get :

```
(bash) $ /usr/local/Anaconda3/bin/mpirun -n 4 demo
Processor [0] : Hello, World! (world=1 processor(s))
Processor [0] : Hello, World! (world=1 processor(s))
Processor [0] : Hello, World! (world=1 processor(s))
Processor [0] : Hello, World! (world=1 processor(s))
```

Running the correct version from a notebook, I get the expected results.

[image]

I had an incompatibility between the two versions (OpenMPI, shipped installed by Anaconda) and MPICH (installed by MacPorts).  Compiling with `mpicc` from one version, and running using `mpirun` from the other version appears to be a bad idea.

Thanks to @jakevdp for this [blog post](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/) which pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: I've tried the same thing, but I get no output at all. I've checked to make sure that the mpicc and the !test mpirun give the same mpi version but I'm clueless as to why the cell shows that it's run successfully with no output at all. Did you modify some parameters for the jupyter notebook before running the above ?